# How can I add a PHP line into Handlebars context array?

Tags: javascript, php, handlebars.js

I am using handlebars and a handlebars register helper to loop through an array that I put in my context and display as an ul. One of the li items needs to have some php in it. I can't figure out a way to put the php into the li.

Here is what I have now:

```
var context = {
  social: [
   { url: "[redacted]"},
   { url: "[redacted]"},
   { url: "[redacted]"},
   { url: "<?php echo get_favorite_toggle('{{post_id}}'); ?>"}
]
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can't figure it out, because you don't fully understand how PHP and Handlebars work. By default, your `<?php ?>` tags will work only in files with PHP extension. And my guess is that your Handlebars templates has `.handlebars` extension.
So, one naive way is to rename this template into `.php`. But this may break other integrations.
The proper way is to require your PHP file using AJAX, and rendering based on the response.

Create a new file, `favorite.php`, for example and put this code:

```
<?php
// Your imports here
$post_id = $_GET['post_id'];

echo get_favorite_toggle($post_id);

?>
```

Now your JS file may look like this:

```
 var context = {
      social: [
         { url: "[redacted]"},
         { url: "[redacted]"},
         { url: "[redacted]"}
      ]
   };
   jqueryNoConflict.ajax({
        url: "/favorites.php?post_id="+post_id,
        success: function (data) {
             context.push({ url: data});
        }
    });
```